# Producer consumer sync using two threads giving unsual serial output

Tags: c, multithreading, producer-consumer

I'm solving a producer / consumer problem using two threads.  I think I've done something wrong because it seems to give the same serial output every time.  What's the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

sem_t empty, full, mutex;

int bound[5];
int a,b;

void *producer(void *arg) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        sem_wait(&empty);
        sem_wait(&mutex);

        printf("%d is produced\n", i);
        sleep(1);

        bound[(++a) % 5] = i;

        sem_post(&mutex);
        sem_post(&full);
    }
}

void *consumer(void *arg) {
    int consumed;

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        sem_wait(&full);
        sem_wait(&mutex);

        consumed = bound[(++b) % 5];

        printf("%d is consumed\n",consumed);
        sleep(1);

        sem_post(&mutex);
        sem_post(&empty);
    }
}

void main() {
    pthread_t prod, con;

    sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1); 
    sem_init(&full, 0, 0);  
    sem_init(&empty, 0, 5);

    pthread_create(&prod,NULL,producer,NULL);
    pthread_create(&con,NULL,consumer,NULL);

    pthread_join(prod,NULL);
    pthread_join(con,NULL);
}
```

Output is like producer first consumes 5 times, then the consumer consumes them all, then producer produces again and repeat:

> ```
> 0 is produced
> 1 is produced
> 2 is produced
> 3 is produced
> 4 is produced
> 0 is consumed
> 1 is consumed
> 2 is consumed
> 3 is consumed
> 4 is consumed
> 5 is produced
> ```

and so on.

Comment: What do you think the output should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because one thread posts a semaphore another thread is waiting for there is no guarantee that the other thread gets to run immediately. If the first thread is very fast it may regain the semaphore before the other thread gets to run. This could be the reason you see alternating series of 5 produced and 5 consumed.

Try making `buf` larger (e.g. 1000) and do 1500 loops in both producer and consumer (also change the `sem_init`). Then you may see another pattern.

BTW: Remove the two sleep calls. They are done while you are holding `mutex` so the other thread can't run anyway.

Comment: I removed the two sleep calls and made buf 100 and did 200 loops.. Still the same output. It's very peculiar

Comment: Is my execution or compilation comman wrong? cc -pthread pcb.c ./a.out

Comment: @AjinkyaPawar No. The output you get is valid. I guess you expected some random pattern. If you don't get that it's simply because you have no code after posting the sems

Answer (score 2):

The fact that some thread is waiting on a semaphore does not mean that it will necessarily unblock as soon as the semaphore's value becomes nonzero, even if it's the only one waiting at that time.  Among the things that can happen is that some other thread that was not already waiting swoops in and acquires it first.

In your code, for example, both producer and consumer post to the `mutex` semaphore and then loop around and try to acquire it again.  Unless blocked by the *other* semaphore, it is entirely possible for one thread to release `mutex` and then reacquire it without the other acquiring it in between.  The fact that your consumer and producer each seem to operate in groups of five items -- corresponding to the counts taken by the `empty` and `full` semaphores -- suggests that this is in fact what is happening.

I would expect you to get perfect alternation if you moved the `sleep` calls outside the critical regions of your thread functions.  And you should do, because otherwise each thread has only a tiny window in which it can take over from the other.

Additionally, although you might find perfect alternation less surprising, it, too, is somewhat odd when you've implemented a production queue longer than one item.  I mean, why would one bother with a queue if there is never more than one item in it?

In order to see more variation in the queue capacity used, you should vary the timing of producer and consumer.  You'll likely want to implement that with a timer having finer resolution than `sleep()` provides, else your runs will take needlessly long.

Comment: Tried it for large values of buffer and removed the sleep calls.. still the same output..

Comment: Is my execution or compilation comman wrong?
cc -pthread pcb.c
./a.out

Comment: @AjinkyaPawar, it is not surprising that you get the same output if you remove the `sleep` calls altogether.  I suggested instead moving them outside the critical regions.  That is, inside the loop, but after the `sem_post`s.  This will give the other thread has a *much* better opportunity to acquire the semaphore first, and it is moreover a better model of what a real-world application would generally want to do.

Comment: The behavior does not arise from an incorrect compilation command.  The output you describe is among those that your code naturally affords.

Comment: Thanx for the suggestion.. i removed the sleep from producer and added it to just consumer outside the critical section.. works great now

Comment: Do u have any idea how to implement this for unbounded buffer ?